# How to make image in imageView selectable in android?

Tags: imageview

I know it is possible to make `text` in `textView` selectable (for copy and paste) using `android:textIsSelectable="true"`.

I want to make `image` in `imageView` selectable (for copy and paste as shown in the image below). Does anyone have a clue?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The Android OS does not support this natively. You will have to register your ImageView with [registerForContextMenu](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#registerForContextMenu(android.view.View)). More info about context menus [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#context-menu).

Then you can get the ImageView's bitmap by doing `((BitmapDrawable)yourImageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();`

See [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/copy-paste.html) for more information on copying the bitmap onto the clipboard.

As a final comment I will say most Android users, myself included, would not expect to be able to long tap an image to copy it onto their clipboard unless there was some indication that it was possible in your app.

Comment: I'll try your suggestion. Please see updated question.

Comment: Right so what you see there is the Chrome's app implementation of what I'm talking about. I forgot to mention you should also hook up a context menu to your LongClickListener and when you click "copy image" that is where you copy the image into the clipboard. I will simplify my answer so you can avoid having to use OnLongClickListener.